# RSA Decryption in Android using private Key

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, private-key

I am using encryption - decryption in Android using public and private key respectively. I have both the keys saved in the RAW folder as a file. The encryption works perfectly, but for the decryption it always gives the following error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
```

I am enclosing the code snippet I have used:

```
public class AppUtils {


public static String encryptString(String value, Context context){
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,  getPublicKey(context) );
        encodedBytes = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public static String decryptString(String value, Context context){
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        //Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "AndroidOpenSSL");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,  getPrivateKey(context) );
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(decodedBytes);
}


public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(Context context){

    // reads the key_public key stored in a file
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key_private);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    try {


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            lines.add(line);


        // removes the first and last lines of the file (comments)
        if (lines.size() > 1 && lines.get(0).startsWith("-----") && lines.get(lines.size()-1).startsWith("-----")) {
           lines.remove(0);
         lines.remove(lines.size()-1);
        }

        // concats the remaining lines to a single String
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String aLine: lines)
            sb.append(aLine);
        String keyString = sb.toString();

        byte [] encoded = Base64.decode(keyString, Base64.DEFAULT);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);

        PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        return myPrivKey;

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static PublicKey getPublicKey(Context context){

    // reads the key_public key stored in a file
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key_public);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;


    try {


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            lines.add(line);

        // removes the first and last lines of the file (comments)
        if (lines.size() > 1 && lines.get(0).startsWith("-----") && lines.get(lines.size()-1).startsWith("-----")) {
            lines.remove(0);
            lines.remove(lines.size()-1);
        }

        // concats the remaining lines to a single String
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String aLine: lines)
            sb.append(aLine);
        String keyString = sb.toString();

        // converts the String to a PublicKey instance
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(keyString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

        return key;
    }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Finally, I call the required function from MainActivity.java like this:

```
String encryptedString =  AppUtils.encryptString("SHANKAR", MainActivity.this);

Log.d("DX1", " Encrypted String " + encryptedString );


String decryptedString =  AppUtils.decryptString(encryptedString, MainActivity.this);

Log.d("DX1", " decrypted String " + decryptedString );
```

I see that, I get the encrypted string properly, but at the time of decryption the statement :

```
PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

is throwing me the above error.But I can decrypt the encrypted string using the private key in any online tool.
Can someone kindly help me out.

My public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgEac6cgM4Ch5vY2Rqvzw2ARaNEHv
PCbXWW1nPy3ft8CNFyLoIltwrnouY0azYECclONARh48qQUQ+UG62wNUtciLq9yX
3m0ePE7u/RYmNUnGWok6LMNZK1gGBu6TBnzNjDWi3CuR00xFzZ2TBtUMDowOa/+b
tfGTywGDLPJjgbtPAgMBAAE=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Can you ensure that you are not unintentionally adding line breaks to your key... after `String keyString = sb.toString();` please attempt: `keyString = keyString.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");`

Comment: you are not suppose to share the private keys here

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried a couple of days to figure out how it works and finally, I got it!

Your private key not in PKCS#8 format.

A PKCS8 key starts with

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

**instead of**

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----.

Java works with PKCS#8 formats.

So you have two ways to fix it:

**First:**

[Regenerate/convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290435/convert-pem-traditional-private-key-to-pkcs8-private-key) your key on the server side in/to PCKS#8 format and use it in android application

**Or Second:**

Convert your private key in the application.
For this way you need include [third party library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/)
to the project.

Add this line into your app Gradle

`compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.56.0.0'`

And replace your `getPrivateKey` method with this:

```java
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(Context context) throws 
    GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
            InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rsa_2048_priv);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line = null;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    lines.add(line);

                if (lines.size() > 1 && lines.get(0).startsWith("-----") && lines.get(lines.size() - 1).startsWith("-----")) {
                    lines.remove(0);
                    lines.remove(lines.size() - 1);
                }

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String aLine : lines)
                    sb.append(aLine);
                String keyString = sb.toString();

                byte[] encodedPrivateKey = Base64.decode(keyString, Base64.DEFAULT);

                try {
                    ASN1Sequence primitive = (ASN1Sequence) ASN1Sequence
                            .fromByteArray(encodedPrivateKey);
                    Enumeration<?> e = primitive.getObjects();
                    BigInteger v = ((ASN1Integer) e.nextElement()).getValue();

                    int version = v.intValue();
                    if (version != 0 && version != 1) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong version for RSA private key");
                    }
                    /**
                     * In fact only modulus and private exponent are in use.
                     */
                    BigInteger modulus = ((ASN1Integer) e.nextElement()).getValue();
                    BigInteger publicExponent = ((ASN1Integer) e.nextElement()).getValue();
                    BigInteger privateExponent = ((ASN1Integer) e.nextElement()).getValue();

                    RSAPrivateKeySpec spec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
                    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                    return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }

        }
```

So it will convert private key to the PKCS#8,
and you can decode your text without error of ***wrong tag***

Hope it help :)

Here the links where I found solutions:

[Getting RSA private key from PEM BASE64 Encoded private key file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216969/getting-rsa-private-key-from-pem-base64-encoded-private-key-file)

[JAVA RSA Decryption not working, throws InvalidKeySpecException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059509/java-rsa-decryption-not-working-throws-invalidkeyspecexception)

[Convert PEM traditional private key to PKCS8 private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290435/convert-pem-traditional-private-key-to-pkcs8-private-key)

[How to include the Spongy Castle JAR in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898801/how-to-include-the-spongy-castle-jar-in-android)